# How can one NSWindow's ID be got

Tags: objective-c, variables, cocoa, member, nswindow

I am new to Obj-c/Cocoa and want to know how to get one NSWindow's ID/number?

The following member variable of NSWindow is found on Apple's website.

```
var windowNumber: Int
The window number of the window’s window device.
```

However how to get it? Shall I just use

```
NSWindow aWindow;
[aWindow getWindowNumber];
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C:

```
NSWindow* myWindow = ...;
NSInteger windowNumber = myWindow.windowNumber;
```

In Swift:

```
let myWindow = ...
let windowNumber = myWindow.windowNumber
```